# Issue in helper content html tag output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following  helper in my template :

```
= link_to t(:site_count, :count => account.subdomains.count ), "#", :rel => 'tooltip', :title => 'Sites', :class => :nofsite, :'data-placement' => "right", :'data-content' => account_sites_html(account), :'data-html' => true
```

using account_sites_html(account) helper to list the account sites with their locales

My helper is correctly producing the html BUT I have an issue with the :class in the language span :

```
 def account_sites_html(account)
    sites = account.subdomains.map {|subdomain| [subdomain.site[:hostname], subdomain.languages]}.uniq
    html = content_tag(:ul) do
        sites.collect do |site|
            content_tag(:li) do
                content_tag(:span, "#{site[0]}")
                site[1].collect do |language| 
                  content_tag(:span, "#{language}", :class => "babFlag-#{language}")
                end.join.html_safe
            end
        end.join.html_safe
    end
    return html.html_safe
  end
```

This produce :

```
"<ul><li><span class=\"babFlag-en\">en</span><span class=\"babFlag-fr\">fr</span></li></ul>"
```

which is badly displayed .... but if I debug and modify the html variable in the console before the return :

```
"<ul><li><span class='babFlag-en'>en</span><span class='babFlag-fr'>fr</span></li></ul>"
```

Then it's fine ... what's wrong with my class string ?

Comment: Have you tried it without the double html_safe calls? I actually don't think you need either one. You definitely don't need the last line of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Rails 3 , need to use concat

concat (content_tag(:span, "#{site[0]}"))